# Does the inequality $|a-b|^p \geqslant 2^{-p}|a|^p - |b|^p$ hold for every $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and $1 \leqslant p < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, solution-verification, real-numbers, exponentiation

I am wondering if the inequality

$$ |a-b|^p \geqslant 2^{-p}|a|^p - |b|^p $$

holds for every $a,b \in \mathbb R$ and every $1 \leqslant p < \infty$.

**My attempt.** First suppose that $|a| < |b|$. Then, since for every $p \in [1,\infty)$ we have that $2^{-p}|a|^p < |a|^p$, it follows that $2^{-p}|a|^p < |b|^p,$ which means that the right-hand side of the inequality is negative, and  thus the inequality trivially holds.

Now let us deal with the case $|a| = |b|.$ In this case we have that

$$ 2^{-p}|a|^p - |b|^p = 2^{-p}|a|^p - |a|^p = \underbrace{|a|^p}_{\geqslant 0}\underbrace{(2^{-p}-1)}_{< 0} < 0, $$
which again means that the inequality trivially holds.

So all that's left is to deal with the case when $|a| > |b|$. I wasn't able to deal with this case bu I am highly confident that the inequality presented holds (I have elaborated a python program that test many different possibilities and all of them seem to be satisfied).

Can anyone help me with this last case?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align*}
\vert a \vert^p &\le (\vert a - b \vert + \vert b \vert)^p \\\\
&\le 2^p [\max(\vert a - b \vert, \vert b \vert)]^p \\\\
&\le 2^p \max(\vert a - b \vert^p, \vert b \vert^p) \\\\
&\le 2^p(\vert a - b \vert^p + \vert b \vert^p)
\end{align*}
$$
Here, note that
$$
   [\max(x, y)]^p = \max(x^p, y^p) \ \forall x, y > 0
$$
and
$$
   \max(x, y) \le x + y \ \forall x, y > 0
$$

Comment: Very nice. On contrast to the answer of Maximilian, this answer requires no prior knowledge of anything advanced besides the inequality $|c+d|^p \leqslant 2^{p-1} ( |c|^p + |d|^p )$, which makes it really interesting in my point of view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality in question is equivalent to

$$\lvert 2(a-b)\rvert^p + \lvert 2b\rvert^p\ge \lvert a\rvert^p,$$

which is true by Jensen's inequality since $x\mapsto \lvert x\rvert^p$ is convex for all $p\in[1,\infty)$.

In fact, even the stronger

$$\lvert 2(a-b)\rvert^p + \lvert 2b\rvert^p\ge 2\lvert a\rvert^p$$ is true.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It is clear. I also had a look at your profile... and I got very interested in your book :) Is there a version of it translated to English?

Comment: @TemirbekAlikhadzhiyev Thank you for your interest! Unfortunately my autobiography exists only in German and French :(

Comment: Oh ok! I will wait and perhaps in the future you think about this translation! Unfortunately I can only accept one answer and I decided to go with Nguyen's one since it requires smaller amount of knowledge... either way I would like to upvote both questions but it seems like I need 15 reputation to do it! All the best for you.